# Проектирование интерфейса администратора

Tags: интерфейс, ui

У меня возник такой вопрос: как сделать лучше? Обстоятельства следующие: необходимо разработать ИС подбора комплектующих ПК в учебных целях, по техническому заданию имеет место и интерфейс администратора, суть его в возможности добавления, редактирования, удаления данных непосредственно из БД в самом приложении, а не напрямую. И сейчас не могу решить: разделить два интерфейса, то есть создать отдельный интерфейс для админа, либо динамически скрывать и показывать элементы управления админа? Разрабатываю на .Net Framework, на c# 7.2, WPF в Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Лучше два отдельных интерфейса, так их легче будет поддерживать и изменять.

Comment: все зависит от количества общих компонентов